# Why not put every server in a unique lan/vlan?

Tags: security, lan

I was thinking, why don't I just put all of our two dozen servers into unique vlans so that I can effectively manage all inter-server firewall rules from the router? (I would keep the OS firewalls running as a backup.)

In my limited reading, I haven't seen this as a recommendation, but it seems to make so much sense to me. 99% of our servers are just silos--you access 'em from the internet, they update their local data, and that's about it. (Though, they do need inbound ssh access from our management lan and outbound internet to pull updates.) The point is, inter-server connectivity is by far the exception. There's no reason to have the servers in a shared lan to ease non-existent communication. There's also no reason to leave each server exposed to the first comprised machine on the lan.

What am I missing? What's the downside of this configuration?

Side note, I *am* starting with the assumption that vlans are available and easy to implement. If you've got a decent router and all of your machines running in modern hypervisors, this seems like a fair assumption.

Answer (score 0):

You can in theory, but you'd send all traffic through the router, which makes it a bottleneck for traffic. Also it'd create a large amount of overhead with many interfaces on the router (one per vlan), many access control lists or seperate places where you need to limit / allow traffic, and generally it'd probably be a big mess....

Usually vlans are used to contain similar security level devices, or hold many devices of a similar role (like phones, printers, or wifi access), or to ring fence a department or other logical grouping of users. This also lets them intercommunicate between themselves without as many restrictions, which is usually a good trade off, but you can further limit that with a layer 3 switch, host based firewall, or some other methods like dedicated firewalls.

When you use a router to force client traffic to move inter-vlan, you're sending all the inter-vlan traffic of the switch up to the router which increases bandwidth usage there. This may or may not be desirable but generally the switch will have a higher throughput than the router so isn't usually a good trade-off.

That said, given the description of your environment, you'd probably get the most mileage out of a network wide firewall combined with simpler host-based firewalls to be configured via a configuration management system (puppet/chef/ansible et al). This allows you an easy method to scale out the firewalling configuration, without the complexity of vlans for every server.

edit: oh, and doing it your suggested way also splits apart the configuration of the servers (i.e: their security) from the servers themselves, which can lead to unneeded extra complexity.

Comment: My main takeaway here is that more traffic hits the router, causing overhead, but since 99% of my traffic is actually between the internet and my machines, that traffic is already hitting the router. By using vlans, I'm just adding overhead to 1% of requests, but I'm gaining centralized host-independent firewall rules. Totally seems worth it.

By "network wide firewall", you mean a firewall between the internet and the internal lan?

Comment: yeah. and no, it's not worth it, because before you had no dependency between the hosts and the networking gear with an easy way to manage and scale out security. Afterwards you have a big ball of mud.